# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I can't understand whats the problem here, I'm sure its something trivial but I'm new to JavaScript so have no clue... The goal here was to change background color and text color (through enabling / disabling css classes) on scroll and reverse it back once on top.

JS

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
  OnScrollWindow();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 120 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 120) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "4px 2px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "#376847";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "10px 5px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}


function OnScrollWindow() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 110 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 110) {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-menu__link");
elements[0].className = "navbar-menu__link--override";
} else {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-menu__link--override");
  elements[0].className = "navbar-menu__link";
}

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].className = "navbar-menu__link navbar-menu__link--override";
}
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="navbar-menu">
     <li><a class="navbar-menu__link"href="#image">images</a></li>
     <li><a class="navbar-menu__link"href="#quotes">quotes</a></li>
     <li><a class="navbar-menu__link"href="#lists">lists</a></li>
     <li><a class="navbar-menu__link"href="#alert">alerts</a></li>
     <li><a class="navbar-menu__link"href="#footer">footer</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    .navbar-menu__link--override {
      color: white;
    }

    .navbar-menu__link {
      color: black;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

The error

```
navbar.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'className')
    at OnScrollWindow (navbar.js:23:25)
    at window.onscroll (navbar.js:3:3)
```

Comment: What is `elements[0]` or `elements[i]` (depending on where the error is being thrown)? I believe `getElementsByClassName()` has to match the *entire* className. I would use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It says the error is on line 23, which would be here:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-menu__link--override");
elements[0].className = "navbar-menu__link"; // <<< ERROR
```

There is no element with `class="navbar-menu__link--override"` at that point, so `getElementsByClassName` returns an empty array. You never check the array length and just read element 0, which will therefore be `undefined`. You then try to set property `className` on it, effectively attempting to do `undefined.className = ...`, which is not possible, hence the error.